# Nagios passive checks, reset service to OK state after notification

Tags: nagios

We have a passive service setup (external server reports issues via passive checks to nagios) and nagios sends out notifications when these services receive a non-ok state.  However, we don't want to have to go in and manually reset the state of that service back to OK,  is there a way to tell nagios to re-set the service back once it's received the non-ok state?  I tried setting "is-volitle" to 1 but that didn't seem to work.  Thanks!

Comment: I am a bit confused here.  Why does being notified mean that the service is now OK?

Comment: In this case the point of the passvie check is just to notify of an issue within the application, but it never re-notifies when the problem is fixed.  It's just to let someone know to go take a look.  We just don't want to have to go manually re set the service state to OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply build a script on the nagios server that submits a passive check with a status of OK.  Define a command in nagios that will call the script with the host and service name.  Setup a notification to be linked with the host and service that will trigger that notification command in addition to any other notifications.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start to create such a script.  I know where the file that nagios checks for passive checks is located.  Can i write to that file directly without causing issue?  I think it's deleted and re-created each time nagios checks it.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create a very simple script based off of this page: http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandinfo.php?command_id=114

Answer (score 1):

Mike, you'll need to read up on Passive checks. I will warn you that passive checks do have a learning curve, the NSCA daemon (Used to collect passive check results from remote servers) is buggy. Most people avoid passive checks.

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/passivechecks.html

There are several possibilities here and you do not provide enough details in your question, so the only thing we can provide for you is general advice. The details are really up for you to figure out and enumerate.

But in a nutshell, yes there ways to reset the state of the service in Nagios. The script which is detecting the error and setting the status to a non-OK status should also detect when the problem is resolved, and should then set the status to "OK".

Typically the way that passive checks work is that a script on a remote server checks something and then sends those results to the NCSA daemon (Or another daemon) on your Nagios server. The script on the remote server should be modified to send an "OK" when the problem has been resolved. The person who created the script should have done this already.

Comment: Thanks for the resources, I've read through the passive checks document already.  We currently have passive checks working for this host.  According to the developer working on this he said there is no way for him to send a "OK" once something is "resolved" for whatever reason.  Anyway i was able to achieve the desired behavior from a script similar to this one: http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandinfo.php?command_id=114

Comment: I was trying to get this to work, as defined in the misccommands.cfg; define command{
        command_name    process-service-check-result
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "[$TIMET$] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;$HOSTNAME$;$SERVICEDESC$;0;$ARG1$;$ARG2$" >> /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
}
however i cant get it to work.  I think the reason is because nagios sees the semi-colon ; as a comment,  I've tried escaping it with a backslash but that didn't work.

Comment: There is not much point in using automated monitoring systems if they require manual intervention. My NSCA checks all say "OK" when things return to normal--  However, the details of this are really all contained within the script which is performing the checks.

Comment: Mike, you are probably looking at the wrong part of the process. The thing that says "OK" is the actual script on the remote server. NSCA is simply the mechanism by which the results are sent to your server-- think of it as analogous to 'NRPE', `check_by_ssh` or `check_by_snmp`. A script is executed somewhere, and the results are passed over the network to the Nagios server using one of these mechanisms.

Comment: I understand how external servers submit passive checks to the NSCA daemon.  I'm referring to how to get nagios to reset the service state back to "OK" after it sends out the alert.  I found out that it is interpreting the semicolon as a comment.  To bypass that you need to quote and escape each semicolon.  "\;".  I was able to get it to work the way I wanted this way.  In the service definition I can now just setup 
event_handler            process-service-check-result!0!OK
after I have the "process-service-check-result" defined like above (with the semicolon fix that is)

Comment: Normally, Nagios resets the service state back to "OK" when the remote script says that the problem is "OK". The remote script should literally send the string "OK" (along with a status code, etc) to NSCA/Nagios, and Nagios will reset the status when it receives that OK.